# office script replace formula with value

Tags: javascript, excel, office365, office-scripts

please advice best way to replace formulas with values.
I used before:

```
//copy-paste values
rEPORT__2_.getRange().copyFrom(rEPORT__2_.getRange(), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.values, false, false);
```

but it stopped to work starting from today. Excel just get unexpected error if i try to copy-paste more tnan 100 rows in one script.
So, is there any other way to replace formalas with values at whoole sheet ?

I tried to use loop (for i). But result almost the same - it process about 50-100 rows with copy-paste and then i just get an error (time-out or unexpected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an effective method for transforming formulas into fixed values.

- Obtain the intersection range to minimize the size of the target range.
- Use the `setValues` function for conversion, as it is more efficient than `copyFrom`.
- Disable auto-calculation before update
- Clear formulas before update cells' value

```js
    let application = workbook.getApplication(); 
    application.setCalculationMode(ExcelScript.CalculationMode.manual);
    const selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("ReportSheet"); // Update name as needed
    let dataRanage = rEPORT__2_.getRange().getIntersection(selectedSheet.getUsedRange());
    let dataValues = dataRange.getValues();
    dataRange.clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents);
    dataRange.setValues(dataValues);     
    application.setCalculationMode(ExcelScript.CalculationMode.automatic);
```

Sample code to convert formula to values on batch (eg. 300 rows)

```js
    let application = workbook.getApplication();
    application.setCalculationMode(ExcelScript.CalculationMode.manual);
    // let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("ReportSheet"); 
    let allRanage = rEPORT__2_.getRange().getIntersection(selectedSheet.getUsedRange());
    let startRow = allRanage.getCell(0,0).getRowIndex();
    let rowCount = allRanage.getRowCount();
    const rowBatch = 300
    for(let i=startRow+1; i<startRow+rowCount+1; i+=rowBatch){
        let lastRow = i+rowBatch-1;
        console.log(i, lastRow)
        let rowRange = selectedSheet.getRange(`${i}:${lastRow}`)
        let dataRange = allRanage.getIntersection(rowRange);
        let dataValues = dataRange.getValues();
        dataRange.clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents);
        dataRange.setValues(dataValues);     
    }
    application.setCalculationMode(ExcelScript.CalculationMode.automatic);
```

---

I have tested it with both Excel Online and Excel 365 desktop. It only takes several seconds.

Test code

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {    
    let application = workbook.getApplication();     
    application.setCalculationMode(ExcelScript.CalculationMode.manual);
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    let dataRange = selectedSheet.getRange("A1:Z5000");
    dataRange.setFormulaLocal("=row()+column()");
    let dataValues = dataRange.getValues();
    dataRange.clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents);
    dataRange.setValues(dataValues);    
    application.setCalculationMode(ExcelScript.CalculationMode.automatic);  
}
```

Comment: It works better, but no result too.  Line 45: Range setValues:The request was aborted.. const selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheet(VrangeVal); // Update name as needed
 let dataRanage = rEPORT__2_.getRange().getIntersection(selectedSheet.getUsedRange());
 dataRanage.setValues(dataRanage.getValues());

Comment: It works better, but no result too.  Line 45: Range setValues:The request was aborted.. It is strange for me because my original code with copy-paste worked till yesterday, And i steel can proceed same steps manually, can record this steps but can not to repeat them with script. It looks like some logic in offfice was changed or some limitations for scripts were added. Looks like not enough resources to proceed this steps. But there is about 3000 rows only to copy and paste values.

Comment: with my original code excel even not start copy-paste (0 rows processed) with your code it process about 120 rows and gets an error.

Comment: I have updated the code. If it doesn't work on your side, please run my test code with a new workbook.

Comment: Line 23: Range setValues: Timeout. It process - 800 - 1200 rows.
That's what i get, but now i inderstand the reason. Excel need to much time to recount formulas and insert values in my file. There a several "heavy" formulas in each row. Is there any way do not recount values in formulas, but just use it as it is. Another way for me - make several scripts and process 500 rows with each of these scripts (launch it one after another).

Comment: Do you apply `clear` before `setValue`? It should fix the re-calculation issue. Are there  lot of formulas out of `dataRanage ` range? I have updated the code to stop auto-cal before update. Please try it.

Comment: Now it works! Thanks a lot! In a final code i changed "application.setCalculationMode" on "workbook.getApplication().setCalculationMode". Here it is:  workbook.getApplication().setCalculationMode(ExcelScript.CalculationMode.manual);
let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
let dataRange = selectedSheet.getRange("A1:AZ2000");
let dataValues = dataRange.getValues();
dataRange.clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.contents);
dataRange.setValues(dataValues);
 workbook.getApplication().setCalculationMode(ExcelScript.CalculationMode.automatic);

Answer (score 0):

- Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select
- Selection.Copy
- Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
- Step1: define the region to copy by choosing a cell inside the continuous range.
- Step2: Copy the selected range.
- Step3: Paste values while still selecting the copied range to replace formulas with values.

Comment: OP is looking for OfficeScript instead of VBA code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).